# Julia: Conditional on For Loop Macros

Tags: for-loop, metaprogramming, julia

Is there an easy way to change a "for loop header" depending on the packages a user has? For example, @progress for is good for adding a progress bar in Juno/Atom (just found out!), while we also have things like @simd, @acc, and @parallel. So what I want to have on this loop is to put a bunch of these macros conditionally given a boolean from the user or depending on availability. However, if I do a simple

`if isdefined(@progress)
  @progress for ...
elseif accelerate
  @acc for ...
elseif
  @parallel for ...
end`

or something of that sort, I would have to keep pasting around the same for loop code. Is there some more elegant way of doing this? Also, I may want to combine some, and so once you start looking at the viable combinations that ends up being a lot of code!

Comment: You can easily make your if, elseif  chain into a macro, maybe called `@myfor` or something. Then you only write that code once when you define the macro. That being said, I'm not sure that applying all available for loop macros is a one-size fits all solution. I personally like being more explicit and writing out the macros in front of the loops I want to apply them to

Comment: The issue with writing them all out is that there's going to be a lot of them, and a lot of different combinations. I am writing a finite element solver, and so what I want to do is have boolean keyword arguments for if it's parallel, whether to put a progress bar on, etc., and have all of the right macros be on the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Pkg.installed` method will error if the package isn't installed.  It takes a string, and returning the decorated expression after that line with the other possibility in the catch block is effective for this sort of thing:

```
macro optional_something(pkg, expr)
    try
        Pkg.installed(string(pkg)) == nothing && return expr
        esc(quote
            @time $expr
        end)
    catch
        expr
    end
end

# this won't add the macro @time
@optional_something XXX rand(1000)    

# this will
@optional_something Plots rand(1000)
```

Comment: Is there a way that this could be changed to use a boolean? The booleans would come from keyword arguments passed into the function, to tell the function some other macros to put on the loop. Some of them will be because of package dependencies (and I like that this one does that automatically!), but others will just be choice. But since macros are run at compile time, I'm not quite sure what it will do when it compiles.

Comment: You mean using runtime values to determine what code the macro produces? No... you can't as those values obviously aren't available at compile time.  You could, however make a macro that creates an if/then block depending on some value.  I leave it as an exercise ;)

Comment: Documentation is wrong then: `help?> Pkg.installed
  installed(pkg) -> Void | VersionNumber

  If pkg is installed, return the installed version number, otherwise return
  **nothing**.
`, but it returns error instead if not installed.

Comment: So if the package is not in metadata it returns an error, but if it is in metadata and not installed it returns `nothing`.

Comment: I updated the macro to reflect this.  It seems like the `Pkg.installed` method should be changed though...